# SwiftData: Batch delete failed due to mandatory OTO nullify inverse

Tags: swift, swift-data

I'm trying to remove all data (for debugging purposes). Let's say I have two models:

```
@Model
class School {
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify, inverse: \Student.school) var students: [Student]

    init(students: [Student]) {
        self.students = students
    }
}
```

and

```
@Model
class Student {
    var school: School?

    init() {}
}
```

I'm trying to delete everything like this:

```
try modelContext.delete(model: School.self)
try modelContext.delete(model: Student.self)
```

But I'm getting the error `Batch delete failed due to mandatory OTO nullify inverse on Student/school`. Why does it say "mandatory" when `school` is an optional value in `Student`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be able to use `delete(model:)` for a type with a relationship then both sides of the relationship needs to be optional.

So you need to change `School`

```
@Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify, inverse: \Student.school) 
var students: [Student]?
```

And if you don’t want to change your model then delete the objects one by one.

*I assume this is a bug that `nullify` is ignored and that it will be fixed in the future.*

Comment: Sadly, the preview seems to be crashing, I posted [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77815130/swiftui-preview-crashes-when-making-swiftdata-one-to-many-relationship-optional). Any idea what could be causing this?